# Defining alternate notation for tikz calc coordinate calculations

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I would like to define an alternate notation for tikz calc coordinate calculations: From, say,

```
    ($ (a,b) + (c,d) $)
```

to something like

```
    \tzcalc{ (a,b) + (c,d) }
```

but I've run into an error I don't know how to correct.

(I'd like to do this to distinguish tikz calculations from math to be typeset. This would make it much easier to write a regex to match only math.)

I've naively defined a new command:

```
    \newcommand{\tzcalc}[1]{($ #1 $)}
```

which works sometimes.

Here is what I have. The part that doesn't work is the `\coordinate` statement toward the end. (It's marked.)

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

    \usepackage{tikz}

    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    \newcommand{\tzcalc}[1]{($#1$)}

    \newcommand{\newcoord}[2]{\coordinate (#1) at ($#2$) ; } % this works.

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \node [left] (a) at \tzcalc{ (0,0) + (135:4) + (45:2) } {$a_0$};
    
        \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
        {
            \draw \tzcalc{ (0,0) + (90:\i) } circle[radius=5pt]; % works
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \newcommand{\basepointx}{2}

        \foreach \j in {0,45,90,135,180,225}
        {
            \coordinate (r\j) at \tzcalc{(\basepointx,-3) + (\j:1) }  ; % doesn't work
            % \node [coordinate] (r\j) at \tzcalc{ (\basepointx,-3) + (\j:1) }  {}; % works
            % \newcoord{r\j}{(\basepointx,-3) + (\j:1)} % works
        }

        \foreach \j in {0,45,90,135}
        {
            \draw (r\j) -- (-5,2);
        }

    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Here is the error:

```
    Runaway argument?
     \tzcalc {(\basepointx ,-3) + (\j :1) } ; \pgffor@endhook \ifx \pgffor@assign@a
    fter@code \ETC.
    ./tik2.tex:38: Paragraph ended before \tikz@@coordinate@@at was complete.
    <to be read again> 
                       \par 
    l.38    
  
    I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
    control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
    My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

Note: `\newcoord` works, but I'd like to avoid using it unless I must. In my view, it would be easier if I could define an alternate to only `($ $)`, rather than define alternates to tikz commands whenever I receive an error.

How might I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried defining it only to replace the `$...$` and not the parentheses?

Comment: TikZ needs to expand `\tzcalc` before it can parse it correctly. It does so at many points but not at all, especially not when the special syntax `coordinate (<name>) at (<point>)` is used. Here, it expects a `(` after the `at` without any exception. Consider the `coordinate` path operation a special quick version of the `node` path operation. (And indeed, each `coordinate` will be converted to a `node[shape=coordinate]` operation which has led to other problems before.) Short story: Deal with it or patch how TikZ parses a coordinate.

Comment: Deal with it means: Either do what @cfr wrote because `\coordinate (r\j) at (\tzcalc{…});` should work with an adjusted `\tzcalc` definition. You can also do `\coordinate[at=\tzcalc{…}](r\j);` Is it really worth it do introduce `\tzcalc`? It's more key strokes than `(`, `$`, `$` and `)`.

Comment: @cfr No! Thank you! That works and is good enough for me.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! I was hoping someone would say how the engine itself is going wrong as a result of my tinkering.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Regarding whether it's really worth introducing ```\tzcalc```, I can certainly appreciate that it's more key strokes than the usual notation. In my case, though, I have several files where I've already drawn diagrams using ```(```, ```$```, ```$```, and ```)```. (continued)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I later found I have to do something to all of the math surrounded by ```$```. It's not hard to write a regex that converts the tikz calculations to use ```\tzcalc```, but it is hard (for me) to write a regex that matches the math, but excludes the tikz calculations, and so I thought to write ```\tzcalc```. No worry! The regex will use ```\tzcalc```. I won't be typing it myself.

Comment: @cfr @Qrrbrbirlbel It seemed to be working, but after leaving it and then trying it again a couple of hours later, the solution no longer works: ```\newcommand{\tzcalc}[1]{$ #1 $}``` and then adding parentheses in the code works in even fewer places.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel ```\coordinate[at=\tzcalc{…}](r\j);``` also doesn't work: ```Cannot parse this coordinate```.

Comment: Yeah, we were wrong, the `$` needs to be explicitly after the `(`. Same problem as with the `(` but it applies everywhere. Re the `at=` approach: With an uptodate TikZ, it should. Alternatively, try `at/.expanded=\tikzcal{…}`.

Comment: It might be easier to figure out the regex .... Do you have maths you need to alter on lines which also include the `calc` syntax?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel No problem. I'll examine your answer! Thanks!

Comment: @cfr It's possible! There are many files.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You're right, ```at=``` works. I had forgotten to revert the definition of tzcalc to include ```( )```.

Comment: Another option: don't worry whether `\tzcalc` works or not. Apply it first. Then run the regexp for the changes to maths. Then revert the `\tzcalc`. The only reason to get rid of the `$...$` is to make the changes, so you only really need something temporary. Whether the code actually compiles at that point doesn't really matter. (Of course, this won't work if you are going to need cycles of changes or to compile the changes for testing, but for a specific known set of changes, it works.) I often use the insertion of `XXX` this way, because it is easy to reverse and only temporary.

Comment: @cfr Thank you! Yes, I thought of this and it was on my list of possible solutions. Related to your final comment: It's indeed possible I might have to make changes to ```$...$``` in the future, at which time I could change ```(* *)``` again, but the regex to change them isn't perfect, and so I have to use other regexes to find the cases missed. If that's what has to be done, there is no helping it, but I thought if I could just change the tikz notation and be done with it, I wouldn't have to go through searching and changing again, if it ever became necessary.

Comment: @cfr Now that the tikz calculations are all changed to use ```\tzcalc```, it's now possible even to change all the math to use ```\(...\)```. That would allow me to revert to ```(* *)``` instead of use ```\tzcalc```. Still, I'm not willing to switch to ```\(...\)``` just yet. In any case, Qrrbrbirlbel's solution seems nice!

Comment: That would give you a more robust solution. But you could also do something like putting all the maths on its own line in the source i.e. insert `%\n\1%\n` where `\1` is the maths. Then future regexps are much easier because you are only concerned with lines which begin with `$` and end `$%`. But @Qrrbrbirlbel is indeed very nice.

Comment: @cfr That would certainly work. I edit the source often, and so would have to be careful to preserve the new scheme. Still, making the math using ```$...$``` unique in the way you suggest would work if I had to make changes immediately and once only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={execute at end picture={%
  \node[draw,lightgray]at(current bounding box){\pgfversion};}}}
\begin{document}

%%% Using the at=\tzcalc{…} syntax with an uptodate TikZ
\begingroup
  \newcommand*\tzcalc[1]{($#1$)}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [left] (a) at \tzcalc{ (0,0) + (135:4) + (45:2) } {$a_0$};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \draw \tzcalc{ (0,0) + (90:\i) } circle[radius=5pt];
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\basepointx}{2}
  
  \foreach \j in {0,45,90,135,180,225}
    \coordinate[at=\tzcalc{(\basepointx,-3) + (\j:1)}] (r\j);
    % Alternative:
    % \coordinate[at/.expanded=\tzcalc{(\basepointx,-3) + (\j:1)}] (r\j);
  
  \foreach \j in {0,45,90,135}
    \draw (r\j) -- (-5,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\endgroup

%%% “Fixing” handling of coordinate path operation
  % (and possibly breaking other things)
\begingroup
  \newcommand*\tzcalc[1]{($#1$)}
  \makeatletter
  \def\tikz@@coordinate@@at[#1](#2)at{%
    \def\tikz@coordinate@caller{\tikz@fig ode[shape=coordinate,#1](#2)at}%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@@coordinate@at@math
  }
  \makeatother
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [left] (a) at \tzcalc{ (0,0) + (135:4) + (45:2) } {$a_0$};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \draw \tzcalc{ (0,0) + (90:\i) } circle[radius=5pt];
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\basepointx}{2}
  
  \foreach \j in {0,45,90,135,180,225}
    \coordinate (r\j) at \tzcalc{(\basepointx,-3) + (\j:1)};
  
  \foreach \j in {0,45,90,135}
    \draw (r\j) -- (-5,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\endgroup

%%% Adjusting \tzcalc definition/usage
  % and “fixing” $ detection
\begingroup
  \newcommand*\tzcalc[1]{$#1$}
  \makeatletter
  \let\origtikz@@@scan@@absolute\tikz@@@scan@@absolute
  \def\tikz@@@scan@@absolute#1(#2){%
    \edef\tikz@temp{#2}%
    \expandafter\origtikz@@@scan@@absolute\expandafter#1\expandafter(\tikz@temp)
  }%
  \makeatother
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [left] (a) at (\tzcalc{ (0,0) + (135:4) + (45:2) }) {$a_0$};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \draw (\tzcalc{ (0,0) + (90:\i) }) circle[radius=5pt];
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\basepointx}{2}
  
  \foreach \j in {0,45,90,135,180,225}
    \coordinate (r\j) at (\tzcalc{(\basepointx,-3) + (\j:1)});
  
  \foreach \j in {0,45,90,135}
    \draw (r\j) -- (-5,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm glad I asked!